# AngularJs ng-class not updated when value changes

Tags: angularjs

I've a simple menu where I would to apply the 'active' class to a clicked link.

Here's part of my menu:

```
<ul>
<li>
   <a href="#/c/{{cId}}" ng-class='{"active":tog==1}' ng-click='tog=1'>{{c}}   
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#/a/{{a.aId}}" class="tree-toggle" 
      ng-class='{"active":tog==2}' ng-click='tog=2'>{{a.Name}}
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

It's really simple structure as I said before, but when I click on first li "c" the class 'active' is set. Then when I click on the second li element the class 'active' is set also on that element and not removed from the first one and set only on the second.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I think it is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/nitishkumarsingh13/9xb1f3yb/

Comment: updated the css to better look the class change http://jsfiddle.net/9xb1f3yb/1/

Comment: I think you use **ui-router** for better and easy to route you app. like : 

    `<a ui-sref="c/{{cId}}" ui-sref-active="active">{{c}}</a>`


see this link:
[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Comment: @s.milziadi please take a look in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me as:

```css
.active{
   font-size: 14pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app>
<li><a href="#" ng-class='{"active":tog==1}' ng-click='tog=1'>Click-Me {{tog}}</a></li>
<li><a href="#" ng-class='{"active":tog==2}' ng-click='tog=2'>Click-Me {{tog}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

Hope it works for you....

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('App', [])
    .controller('InputCtrl', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.cId = 1;
        $scope.c = 'some text';
        $scope.a = {};
        $scope.a.Name = 'some text in a';

 
      }
    ]);

}());
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="InputCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a ng-href="" ng-class='{"active":tog==1}' ng-click='tog=1'>{{c}}   
   </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="tree-toggle" ng-class='{"active":tog==2}' ng-click='tog=2'>{{a.Name}}
   </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```